# How do I install the default unity-lens packages?

Tags: unity, package-management

So I did something stupid and got rid of the default Unity Lenses.

How would I restore those?

Comment: Do you know exactly what you did?

Answer (score 1):

With a quick search through the repos, these are the packages I have installed for lenses:

```
unity-lens-gwibber unity-lens-video unity-lens-friends unity-lens-files unity-lens applications unity-lens-music
```

Try installing them:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-gwibber unity-lens-video unity-lens-friends unity-lens-files unity-lens applications unity-lens-music
```

And then run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I'm not sure this will work, it depends on what exactly you did to mess the lenses up.